# How to create a zoomable map of the world with different selectable countries in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to create a zoomable map of the world with different selectable countries?
Like [**this example**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srMNB.jpg) from the game "plaque inc" for android where I selected the USA.

For my game I am **not** using a game development framework like libgdx and want to do this as simple as possible.

Could this be done just by using a layout file and different graphics for each country?

I am using **Java** and Eclipse.

Comment: then your best option is use an image as background and add listeners to the zones you need to be clickable.

Comment: @JordiCastilla How to define these zones or countries which are not of rectangular shape because every country has a different shape?

Comment: use non rectangular shapes and add them listeners, I cannot help you with this, sorry, not a deeper *connaisseur* of layouts ;)

Comment: How do I create a layout which consists of different graphics for each country with different shapes that are so aligned that they create a picture of the world?

Comment: Nono... You must use the map as image background, then define transparnt cluckable areas to *simulate* clicks... Thats rhe way usually is done, you dont click directly objects you click areas that move objects ;)